# How to select an element in Jsoup using its html content?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to select an element in Jsoup using its html content.

Example: LOCATION:

How can i do it. I couldn't find any approriate selector methods directly. Is there any work around available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jsoup library you can parse from value from html using name, ID or class of element.

```
String html = "<html><head><title>Title</title></head> <body><div id='location'>Mumbai, India</div></body></html>";
Document document= Jsoup.parse(html);
String content = document.getElementById("location").outerHtml();
```

Happy Coding :-)